# Example of countably additive function on sigma-algebra, $\mu$, where $\mu(\emptyset)\neq 0$

Tags: measure-theory

You have a measure space $(X, A)$ and $\mu:A\to [0, +\infty]$ is a countably additive function on $A$, a sigma algebra. What would be an example where $\mu(\emptyset)\neq 0$? I am assuming I have to take an example where $\mu(A)$ is negative...

Comment: If $u:A\to[0,+\infty]$ and $u(\emptyset)\ne0$, then $u(\emptyset)=+\infty$ and so $u(B)=+\infty$ as well for all $B\in A$.

Comment: "I am assuming I have to take an example where $\mu(A)$ is negative." For two reasons, this sentence doesn't make much sense.  First, $A$ is not a set; it's a collection of sets.  Second, you say in your first sentence that $\mu\colon A \to [0, +\infty]$, so how can any output be negative?

Answer (score 2):

If $\mu$ is countably additive and $\mu(\varnothing)<\infty$, then we have $$\mu(\varnothing)=\mu(\varnothing\cup\varnothing)=\mu(\varnothing)+\mu(\varnothing).$$Subtracting the one on the left over, we have $$0=\mu(\varnothing).$$Therefore, if $\mu(\varnothing)\neq0$, then we have $\mu(\varnothing)=\infty$, and $\mu(B)=\infty$ for all $B\in A$, the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable subsets as $\varnothing\subseteq B$.

Comment: ... assuming that everything $u(\varnothing) < \infty$, of course.